# When passing LWC variable to Visualforce page coming as blank

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, component

I have a blank LWC component where I am just checking the device form factor and trying to pass the same to a Visualforce page. But some reason the process is not working. No values are coming on the Visualforce page. But the reverse process is working fine, I mean from Visualforce to LWC. Below is my code -

**redirectionURL.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import redirectURL from '@salesforce/apex/RedirectController.redirect'
import FORM_FACTOR from "@salesforce/client/formFactor";

export default class HyperlinkRedirect extends LightningElement {
    @api paramValue;
    @api device;
    
    connectedCallback(event) {
        var currentDevice
        if(FORM_FACTOR === 'Large'){
            currentDevice = 'Desktop'
        }
        else if(FORM_FACTOR === 'Medium'){
            currentDevice = 'Tab'
        }
        else if(FORM_FACTOR === 'Small'){
            currentDevice = 'Mobile'
        }
        
        // Send data to vf page.
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
            'getdata', 
                {
                    detail: { device:  currentDevice},
                    bubbles: true,
                    composed: true,
                }
            ));
            
        redirectURL({
            deviceType: currentDevice,
            urlValue: this.paramValue
        }).then(result => {
            if (result != null) {
                window.open(result, "_self")
                
            } else {
                //alert('Error in Redirection')
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**RedirectionPage.vfp**

```
    <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="RedirectController">
    <apex:includeLightning />    
    <div id="lightningvf" />
    
    <script>
    window.addEventListener("getdata", function(event){
        alert('vf event data:: ', +event.detail.device);   // It is coming as a blank value
    });
    
    $Lightning.use("c:RedirectionApp", function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:hyperlinkRedirecter",
                                   {
                                       paramValue:'{!actualUrl}'
                                   },
                                   "lightningvf",
                                   function (component) {
                                       //alert("Lwc Component is being used in VF Page::");
                                   }
                                  );
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Can someone please help me why no value is coming from LWC to Visualforce? Am I missing any syntax or logic here?